# PHP script with sleep() does not exit on connection close

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that does this:

```
$sec = 1;
$id = 1;
while ($sec<20) {
    sleep(1);
    mysql_query("update test set sec = $sec where id = $id");
    $sec++;
}
```

Whenever I load the script in my browser, it will keep on going even if I closed the browser window after 5 seconds. How can I change this so when the browser window is closed, the script will exit?

Comment: What's wrong with your script? You're not testing at all for the browser close event (if it's even possible server-side!), you just test for 20 secs and that's it. What do you wonder about?

Comment: @hakre sorry i didn't understand your comment..

Comment: You've been asking a question but I see no effort in your code that shows/aims for what you're asking for.

Comment: You're asking how to battle the downsides of a solution you shouldn't have been using from the start. The problem is rooted much deeper in your application, perhaps you can elaborate on that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Once the HTTP request has been sent off to the server, the PHP script will continue to execute to it's end even if the client has disconnected.

There might be some cases where a script will exit while printing things, but seeing as you're not printing anything it won't exit.

Comment: Can I achieve this with ``header`` redirects maybe?

Comment: You could redirect with a `header()` call, but you still don't know when/if the user disconnects.

Comment: Looks like there are several php functions that were designed to check if the connection is still alive, but after trying all of them, none works..

Comment: Even if I print something to the screen, script won't exit using any of the connection handling functions

Comment: 'something' is to arbitrary.... Any caching on server, proxies, network prevents the network prevents the webserver detecting a disconnect. Sending a _massive_ amount of whitespace may help (do `flush()` this, but for all practical purposes, _"you can't"_ is as close to right as possible.

Comment: @Wrikken Tried using ``flush()`` but it didn't help.. I see a lot of people who supposedly succeeded using the php connection handling functions (as documented on the comments for these php functions). What is the reason they could do it but I can't?

Comment: @user838437: __anything_ in the network setup, although local to PHP  out-buffering (check `ob_get_level()` whether it is on) could be the cause, the cause could be anywhere on the network between the UA and PHP, which is why _'you can't'_ is about the correct answer.

Comment: @Wrikken ``echo ob_get_level();`` returns 1

Comment: So.... the documentation hints at..... I'll give you a minute....... Nearly there........ Ah, well, here's the answer: `ob_flush()`.

Comment: @Wrikken, thanks for your help. It's strange, it works on FF but not on IE or chrome for some reason..

Comment: Nothing strange about it, we keep telling you you cannot control buffering behavior... You can hint at what you want, but if you _need_ it you need to rethink your design.

Comment: Normal TCP disconnection (using FIN) should be detected by the O/S, then  apache and handled by php somehow.

Answer (score 1):

the ignore_user_abort function sets whether a client disconnect should abort script execution or not. You need to add this in the beginnig of your script

```
ignore_user_abort(false);
```

Comment: This doesn't work.. placed this at the top but still when I close the browser/tab the script continues to update the mysql record.

Comment: try to add an output at the end of the loop so php can detect user abort better. You can echo a space for example.

Answer (score 1):

An awful lot depends on what information the webserver will pass back to the PHP interpreter - even running as a CLI, PHP may only detect the client has aborted when it tries to write to its pty.

In some cases, the webserver *may* send a signal to the interpreter. But there is no reliable way from PHP to detect if the HTTP connection really has been aborted.

But goven the complications inherent in maintaining long connections over HTTP, it rather begs the question of why you want to create a scenario where this occurs normally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a session variable that destroys when you close the browser and if that is not anymore set you can break the operation.

Comment: tried this, didn't work. I set up a ``session_start()`` at the beginning of the script and also set up a ``$_SESSION['alive'] = 1`` and kept checking if it exists before I launch the update command.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP script is runs in a process on your web server. Simply closing the browser does not necessarily terminate this process. This means that your script may continue to execute, even if the browser connection is closed.

It can be configured not to do this however...

look at the function

```
ignore_user_abort();
```

putting this at the top of your script should stop it from running after the user closes the browser

```
ignore_user_abort(false);
```

Comment: This doesn't work.. placed this at the top but still when I close the browser/tab the script continues to update the mysql record.

Comment: try once.  echo something in your script. because PHP will not detect that the user has aborted the connection until an attempt is made to send information to the client

Comment: Even after echoing something in the script, it won't stop when I close it down.

Answer (score 0):

[PHP connection_aborted() Does not always works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530820/php-connection-aborted-does-not-always-works/29401757#29401757)

TCP requires that ALL sent packets be acknowledged by the client and therefore the server should detect this as a send timeout at the very least...

```
session_write_close();//to make flush work
while (connection_status() !== 0) {//this will work if the connection is properly shutdown
                                   //or if it is simply disconnected...
  sleep(1);
  echo "whatever";
  ob_flush();
  flush();
}
```