# PHP connection_aborted() Does not always works

Tags: php, connection, client

First of all i read many of the topics in stackoverflow about connection_aborted before making this topic but i didn't find the solution i wanted.

I want the below script to end properly when the connection has been terminated between the server and the client. Sometime works , sometimes not. I don't know why.

The sample code is the following:

```
<?php

ignore_user_abort( true );
register_shutdown_function( 'shutdown' );


$url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000";
$file_handler = @fopen( $url, "rb" ) or die("Open failed");

foreach ( $http_response_header as $h )
{
    header( $h );
}

$bytes = 0;
while ( ! feof( $file_handler ) and ! connection_aborted() )
{
    $response = stream_get_line( $file_handler, 4096 );
    $bytes += strlen( $response );
    echo $response;
}

fclose( $file_handler );


function shutdown()
{
    global $file_handler;

    if ( ! is_null( $file_handler ) )
    {
        fclose( $file_handler );
        //do some other code
    }

    posix_kill( getmypid(), 9 );
}

?>
```

What do i need to do to make it more accurate?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The meaning `connection_aborted()` is, that the server **knows**, that the connection to the client has been lost. As it happens, this very often is not the case:

- Think of the client unplugging the network cable, walking out of WiFi coverage, driving into a underground carpark with his mobile: No packet that says, that the connection was terminated is ever communicated between the client and the server. This means, that the server will learn about the connection dropping only, when sending the reply is unsuccessfull - possibly long after your script has ended.
- Think of a busy server (network-busy): It is quite likely, that the connection.ending packet is received and processed at the webserver only after your script has gone on running for an appreciable time.

Long story short: It is a property of TCP, that loss of connection might ot might not be detected immediately.

Comment: Yes i understand that it can not detect it exactly at the time when the user disconnected but in my situation when a user successfully disconnects does NEVER close! the php script PID still remains open and the only way to close it is to kill it manually. 

I have no idea why this happening though. Is there any issue with the buffer? Do i need to use flush or something else? I think i tried them but they didn't work.

Comment: Doing something, that needs to be undone on premature end of script and relying on `connection_aborted()` will simply not work reliably. No flushing and no other trick will change the reality of how TCP works.

Answer (score 0):

TCP requires that ALL sent packets be acknowledged by the client and therefore the server should detect this as a send timeout at the very least...

```
session_write_close();//to make flush work
while (connection_status() !== 0) {//this will work if the connection is properly shutdown
                                   //or if it is simply disconnected...
  sleep(1);
  echo "whatever";
  ob_flush();
  flush();
}
```

Comment: If the client fails to ack, the server will send again. and again, opening the TCP window, ... It is not only likely, but nearly certain, that the broken state of the connection will be detected only after the script has finished.

Comment: So what is `SO_SNDTIMEO` for in the Berkeley sockets api? My understanding is that PHP uses the operating system libraries for tcp sockets and even window's Winsock api uses an api that is semantically equivalent to Berkeley sockets. As long as I set a send timeout then a failure to ack will be detected.

Comment: You can chose your poison: Make total timeout so small, that you can no longer reliably talk to a slow other end, or risk not detecting it at all.